# How to display images saved in a JSON format in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, image

I've tried everything under the sun and even browsed a lot of the solutions on stack overflow, but could not find a way around the issue.
The images alone simply don't want to display for one reason or another.
Everything else is working fine but the images.

```js
<section className='profiles'>
    {
        profiles.map(data => <Person key={data.id} name={data.name} img={data.img} position={data.position} desc={data.desc} comittee={data.comittee} />)
    }
</section>
```

Here's the json file:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "comittee": false,
        "img": "require('@img/person1.jpg')",
        "desc": "Here's a short description about the person above and what they do and love not to do",
        "position": "member",
    },

    {
        "id": 1,
        "comittee": false,
        "img": "img/person2.jpg",
        "desc": "Here's a short description about the person above and what they do and love not to do",
        "position": "member",
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you add the css and js code of the `<Person>` component?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example code for display images from a JSON.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const people = [
    { name: 'Person 1', img: '/images/person1.svg' },
    { name: 'Person 2', img: '/images/person1.svg' },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {people.map(({ name, img }) => (
        <Person key={name} name={name} img={img} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

function Person({ name, img }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name}</p>
      <img src={img} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live example:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vunpjf?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: just to have the better accessibility, we can add "alt" attribute to the "img" tag with the "name" prop passed in Person component.